# Is there more than one item that your clone drops after drinking the X potion

Tags: candy-box-2

I was playing and wondered if it was worth it to fight my clone twice?

Answer (score 1):

No.

The only reward for defeating yourself is the Boots of Introspection. Once you have them, there's no reward for fighting yourself again.